# Ensure that the next function starts when the previous is complete. Keep all of the target elem's registered events disabled until the job is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this markup:

```
<span class="click">click</span>
<div><span>first child</span>, <span>second child</span>, <span>third child</span></div>
```

After clicking ".click" (let's call it "target"), I want:
1. add " done" html to the first child of the next div, like this:

```
$('.click').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next('div').children('span').first().html(function () {
        return $(this).html() + ' done';
    });
});
});
```

2. ONLY AFTER the previous function is complete, add " done" html to the third child of the target's next div;
3. ONLY AFTER the previous function is complete, `alert ("third child done. coming to second...")`;
4. ONLY AFTER the previous function is complete, add " will be the last elem to deal with" html to the second child of the target's next div;
5. Finally, ONLY AFTER the previous function is complete, `alert ('the job is done')`;
6. Since those functions may require a long time to be completed, even maybe involving multiple setTimeouts, I must disable all events associated with ".click" until the entire logic is complete (in this particular case, it means they will be enabled after `alert ('the job is done')`).
Maybe use $.Deferreds? Or create some kind of callbacks?..

Comment: you want to add "done" to each span?

Comment: I thought I had clarified the exact order: " done" to the first, **when it is already added** - " done" html to the third , **when added** - alert, OK - " will be the last elem to deal with" html to the second, alert, OK, and you're able to click `.click` again.

Comment: FIRST THIRD SECOND is the order?

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter! Yes, I deal with the third at first, and then with the second, that's exactly what I want. And if you have previous function inside `setTimeout`, next function must start after this previous function is done!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FE6jF/

Comment: No, that sure is a wrong approach. In your example, first alert comes when no modification of the first span's html is visible. By the way, I didn't say I needed an alert after the first modification :) Besides, this code won't do the right thing if the first function is inside a setTimeout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21800/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-lyrically-wicked)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is deferred objects. Made available in jQuery 1.5.

With deferred objects you can orchestrate your function calls like so

```
functionOne().done( function2, function3, function4 )
```

Take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: I just can't understand how exactly the code should look like, for this particular case.

Comment: If some function has `$(this)`, next is function(param1), second is function(param2), how to pass these different parameters with `.resolve()`, is it necessary to use `.promise()`, how the starting code would look like?..